# Secure node,js API routes

Tags: node.js

Im wondering how could I prevent replay attack on my Node.JS API routes. I plan to use the API inside my app. The request URL and payload can be viewed on `mitmproxy`.

Anyone could easily send the same request without using app. How could I protect the routes so only authorized requests from the app can be accepted?

Comment: Use https and make the app refuse to send any sensitive data if the server fails https certificate check.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [JWT](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token) for your use case. In this way only users with valid token can access API.